# How to change autocomplete_route_parameters value on change of select option?

Tags: 8, routes

How to change autocomplete_route_parameters value on change of select option?

I have a form element and inside autocomplete_route_parameters, I want to change $langcode value when I select any language from select list.

```
$form['node_items'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'autocomplete_node_search.autocomplete',
            '#autocomplete_route_parameters' => array('skip_node_id_string' => $skip_node_id_string, 'langcode' => $langcode),

          );
```

So if I choose language french from select list, $langcode should become = 'fr' via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below example to do that.

https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example%21ajax_example.module/function/ajax_example_dependent_dropdown/7.x-1.x

Customized it as listed below.

```
$form_state_values = $form_state->getValues();
if (!empty($form_state_values['language'])) {
  // write your logic here to prepare $skip_node_id_string & $langcode
}
$form['first'] = [
 '#type' => 'textfield',
 '#title' => $this->t('first'),
 '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'autocomplete_node_search.autocomplete',
 '#autocomplete_route_parameters' => 
 array('skip_node_id_string' =>$skip_node_id_string, 
 'langcode' => $langcode),
 '#prefix' => '<div id="change-lang-wrap">',
 '#suffix' => '</div>',
];
$form['language'] = [
 '#type' => 'select',
 '#title' => $this->t('language'),
 '#options' => ['someval'],
 '#ajax' => [
  'callback' => [$this, 'changeLanguage'],
  'event' => 'change',
  'wrapper' => 'change-lang-wrap',
 ],
];
// Ajax callback.
public function changeLanguage(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
 return $form['first'];
}
```

Hope this will fix your issue.

Tried below links, but no luck.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1135288